# trying to have a list of users in three vertical columns

Tags: html, css

Im trying to do a structure like I have in my image below. A list of users with 3 items in each column.

But Im not having sucess doing this.

[image]

I have my example here with what Im having: 
http://jsfiddle.net/81j72gx1/2/

Can you give me a help to understand what is wrong in my code?

This is my html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="left">
            <h1>Services</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <span>User:</span>
            <span>John</span>
            <a href="#">(close)</a>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>User</h2>
        <form>
            Order by:<select>
                <option value="Test" name="test">test</option>
                <option value="Test" name="test">test</option>
                <option value="Test" name="test">test</option>
            </select>
            All: <select>
                <option value="Test" name="test">test</option>
                <option value="Test" name="test">test</option>
                <option value="Test" name="test">test</option>
            </select>
             Status:<select>
                <option value="Test" name="test">test</option>
                <option value="Test" name="test">test</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" Value="Update"/>
        </form>
        <div id="lists_container">
            <div class="list1">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x80"/></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="list2">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x80"/></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="list3">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/50x80"/></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#wrapper{
width:900px; margin:0 auto;
}
#header{
width:100%; float:left;
}
#header #left {
float:left;
}
#header #right {
float:right;
}
#header #right a{
color:#000;
}
#menu{
width:100%; float:left; height:50px; background:#ccc;
}
#menu ul{
list-style:none;
}
#menu ul li {
float:left;line-height:50px;
}
#menu ul li a{
text-decoration:none; color:#000; display:block; margin-right:20px;
}
#menu ul li a:hover{
color:#fff; background:#000;
}
#content {
float:left; width:100%; margin-top:20px;
}
#lists_container{
float:left;width:100%;
}

.list1 ul li img{
float:left; margin-right:10px;
}

.list1 ul li{
 list-style:none;
 }
.list2{
 float:left;
 }
.list2 ul li img{
 float:left; margin-right:10px;
 }
.list2 ul li{
 list-style:none;
 }
.list2 ul{
 list-style:none;
 }
.list3 ul{
 list-style:none;
 }
```

Comment: why don't you just use a table, which is much easier to work with, especially in your case.

Comment: Its better if you can work with some div classes or with some tables ... as your code seems to be very complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no time to debug your code, but I'm providing you with a solution that is quite clean in order to display a grid of results.

Check it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ez22e9xv/1/

You should just adjust the width of every li element to match your container's width, or if your width is auto, it will be kind of "responsive".

Css:

```
ul.myList {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 0 0 -10px;
    padding:0;
}

ul.myList li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;
}

ul.myList li img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

ul.myList li span {
    display:block;
}
```

Html:

```
<ul class="myList">
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x80" />
        <span class="name"><a href="#">John Cooper</a></span>
        <span class="number">Nº 20</span>
        <span class="email"><a href="#">john@email.com</a></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x80" />
        <span class="name"><a href="#">John Cooper</a></span>
        <span class="number">Nº 20</span>
        <span class="email"><a href="#">john@email.com</a></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x80" />
        <span class="name"><a href="#">John Cooper</a></span>
        <span class="number">Nº 20</span>
        <span class="email"><a href="#">john@email.com</a></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x80" />
        <span class="name"><a href="#">John Cooper</a></span>
        <span class="number">Nº 20</span>
        <span class="email"><a href="#">john@email.com</a></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x80" />
        <span class="name"><a href="#">John Cooper</a></span>
        <span class="number">Nº 20</span>
        <span class="email"><a href="#">john@email.com</a></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x80" />
        <span class="name"><a href="#">John Cooper</a></span>
        <span class="number">Nº 20</span>
        <span class="email"><a href="#">john@email.com</a></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x80" />
        <span class="name"><a href="#">John Cooper</a></span>
        <span class="number">Nº 20</span>
        <span class="email"><a href="#">john@email.com</a></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x80" />
        <span class="name"><a href="#">John Cooper</a></span>
        <span class="number">Nº 20</span>
        <span class="email"><a href="#">john@email.com</a></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x80" />
        <span class="name"><a href="#">John Cooper</a></span>
        <span class="number">Nº 20</span>
        <span class="email"><a href="#">john@email.com</a></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x80" />
        <span class="name"><a href="#">John Cooper</a></span>
        <span class="number">Nº 20</span>
        <span class="email"><a href="#">john@email.com</a></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x80" />
        <span class="name"><a href="#">John Cooper</a></span>
        <span class="number">Nº 20</span>
        <span class="email"><a href="#">john@email.com</a></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x80" />
        <span class="name"><a href="#">John Cooper</a></span>
        <span class="number">Nº 20</span>
        <span class="email"><a href="#">john@email.com</a></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very nice and simple solution!